# Deploy Powerpoint templates over Office 365

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, office365, templates, deployment, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

Our company has Office 365 with the Office 2016 suite and Sharepoint Online.

I'd like to know if it's possible to push our custom templates to all users in Powerpoint and change the default create new templates for ours.

Thanks